# Loop through object and order sub values

Tags: javascript, mysql, loops, assign

First of all:

I created a forum structure in MYSQL:

Table: `[boards]` -> id, parent_board, title, description

Simple and good.

This is the database response:

```
[{"id":1,"parent_board":0,"title":"Lorem 1","description":"ec40db959345153a9912"},
{"id":2,"parent_board":0,"title":"Lorem 2","description":"bb698136a211ebb1dfedb"},
{"id":3,"parent_board":1,"title":"Lorem 1-1","description":"6062bc28a9f781e06417d"}]
```

As you can see **board id 3** is a sub-board of **board id 1** since its `parent_board` value is set to **1**.

I would like to receive the following output:

- Lorem 1

  - Lorem 1-1
- Lorem 2

But this is my result:

- Lorem 1
- Lorem 2

  - Lorem 1-1

*How can I loop this object so that sub-board (board 3) will be below board 1?*

I use the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.

Here is my code:

```
var html = "</ul>";

for(var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){

    if(boards[i].parent_board == 0){

        html += "<li>" + boards[i].title + "</li>";

    }else{

        html += "<ul>";

        html += "<li>" + boards[i].title + "</li>";

        html += "</ul>";
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015449/generating-nested-list-from-flat-list-with-parent-child-lists-in-javascript shows how to turn the flat array into hierarchical objects. It should be relatively straightforward to adapt it to printing the nested lists.

Comment: That looks great Barmar, thank you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put an ID attribute on the `<li>` for each board.  Then whenever I iterate through a sub-board, I just append the new items as children of the parent with the matching id, to do this, you would have to create and add each element to the document as you encounter them instead of storing them in a string first.

```
var htmlElem = document.getElementById('htmlElemId');
htmlElem.innerHTML = "";

for(var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){
  if(boards[i].parent_board == 0){
    htmlElem.innerHTML += "<li id='" + boards[i].id + "'>" + boards[i].title + "</li>";
  }else{
    var parent = document.getElementById(boards[i].parent_board);
    if (parent){
      parent.innerHTML += "<ul><li id='" + boards[i].id + "'>" + boards[i].title + "</li></ul>";
    }
  }
}
```

Replace 'htmlElemId' with the actual id of your container element, and also make sure that it is of type `<ul>`.

EDIT: You may also want to consider using some kind of prefix in your ID, so you aren't just using plain numbers that could conflict with things elsewhere

```
"<li id='SomePrefix-" + boards[i].id + "'>" + boards[i].title + "</li>"

var parent = document.getElementById("SomePrefix-" + boards[i].parent_board);
```

EDIT2: Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lochemage/xkyuw9ma/)

Comment: You are great my friend. Here the result: http://puu.sh/aIZ61/c41d868495.png  Thank you very very much!