# change parent child related ids of nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, object

I have following array of objects

```
{
  id: 'a',
  parent_id: 'root'
}

    {
        id: 'a1',
        parent_id: 'a'
    }

        {
          id: 'a11',
          parent_id: 'a1'
        }
        {
          id: 'a12',
          parent_id: 'a1'
        }
        {
          id: 'a13',
          parent_id: 'a1'
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

    {
        id: 'a2',
        parent_id: 'a'
    }

        {
          id: 'a21',
          parent_id: 'a2'
        }
        {
          id: 'a22',
          parent_id: 'a2'
        }
        {
          id: 'a23',
          parent_id: 'a2'
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

I have one root element with the id `a` and it has multiple children ( children are saved with `parent_id` property)

I'm saving in the same format in mongodb. I want to share same records with another user and

My data model needs these Ids to be unique, so I just want to copy these array of objects into a separate var and changes these id's to random strings maintaining parent and child relationship.

I can generate random string from one of the libraries using `Random.id()` now I don't know how to loop through all the children and change the `id` and `parent_id` property, any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The ids are already unique.. what's the problem.? Do you want to nest the object structure?

Comment: @Redu I want to save same set of cards to different user, so I have to save same set of `_id` to same collection. That's why before I save same set of collection to different user I want to change ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this might be what you wanted;

```js
function  makeUniqueId(){
  var   id = "",
  charList = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
   numList = "0123456789";
  for( var i=0; i < 2; i++ ) id += charList.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charList.length));
  for( var j=0; j < 3; j++ ) id += numList.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  return !~uil.indexOf(id) ? (uil.push(id),id) : makeId();
}
var uil = [], // unique id list
   data = [
  {
    id: 'a',
    parent_id: 'root'
},{
    id: 'a1',
    parent_id: 'a'
},{
    id: 'a11',
    parent_id: 'a1'
},{
    id: 'a12',
    parent_id: 'a1'
},{
    id: 'a13',
    parent_id: 'a1'
},{
    id: 'a2',
    parent_id: 'a'
},{
    id: 'a21',
    parent_id: 'a2'
},{
    id: 'a22',
    parent_id: 'a2'
},{
    id: 'a23',
    parent_id: 'a2'
}];

data.forEach((e,i,a) => {var puid = makeUniqueId();
                         a.forEach(f => f.parent_id == e.id && (f.parent_id = puid));
                         e.id = puid;
                        });
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Everytime you run the code you will get different unique values for the `id` and `parent_id` fields. If you want to get this one get nested then it's a total different story.

Comment: yeah these cards are deeply nested so I want solution for `n` level. Thank you for the answer

Comment: The above code assigns correct unique ids according to the originally provided parental relationship. All you have to do is to run it each time you need to generate a new set with  unique ids. However if you would like to get this flat structure nested then check this answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/37208104/4543207

Answer (score 1):

I figure out a solution, you can dig into the code...

The code find the max id, and then, walk the tree, changing the ids, if you need a alfanumeric id, you can make some kind of random id and use the same walking function.

```js
var data = [{id: 10, parent_id:null}, {id: 20, parent_id:10}];

function findTopLevel() {
  return data.find(function(val, i, arr) { return val.parent_id == null || val.parent_id == undefined });
};

function findChildren(parent) {
  return data.filter(function(val, i, arr) { return val.parent_id == parent.id });
};

function findMaxId(node, max) {
  max = Math.max(node.id, max || -1);
  var children = findChildren(node);
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    max = findMaxId(children[i], max);
  }
  return max;
};

function walk(parent) {
  var parentId = ++maxId;
  var children = findChildren(parent);
  parent.id = parentId;
  for (var i in children) {
    children[i].parent_id = parentId;
    walk(children[i]);
  }
};

var topLevel = findTopLevel();

var maxId = findMaxId(topLevel);

walk(topLevel);

console.log(maxId, data)
```